# How to integrate the React Native 0.42.3 in a XCode project using cocoapods

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am trying to add React Native 0.42.3 to an existing XCode project. The process of integrating it needs to be automated because the Xcode project is generated every time you build an app.

It looks like there were a bunch of changes in the latest releases of the React Native. I am using the following PodFile to add all the dependencies:

```
     # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks

  pod "RSKImageCropper"
  pod "QBImagePickerController"

  react_native_path = "../node_modules/react-native"
  yoga_path = File.join(react_native_path, 'ReactCommon/yoga')

  pod "Yoga", :path => yoga_path
  pod "React", :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]


end
```

It seems to add all the necessary dependencies, but I am having conflicts after I link other dependencies using the react-native link command. Also, I need to manually update the build scheme settings.

Is there a way to automate the process of adding the dependencies so it would aways reliably add them? Does anyone have an example of a podfile for the latest release of the react native?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following PodFile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  react_native_path = "../node_modules/react-native"
  yoga_path = File.join(react_native_path, 'ReactCommon/yoga')

  pod "Yoga", :path => yoga_path
  pod "React", :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
    'jschelpers',
    'cxxreact',
    'ART',
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTPushNotification',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]

  pod "RSKImageCropper"
  pod "QBImagePickerController"

end
```

There are still changes remaining, such as adding jsbundle to the project and editing the build scheme, I decided to set these changes in a pod post install hook.